# Счётчик в сервлете увеличивается на 2 а не на 1

Tags: java, tomcat, servlet, rest

Сервлет:

```
@WebServlet("/")
public class MainServlet extends HttpServlet {
    double counter = 0;
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        req.setAttribute("counter", counter);
        req.setAttribute("name", "VII");
        req.getRequestDispatcher("mypage.jsp").forward(req, resp);
        counter++;
    }
}
```

Страничка jsp:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Helo, ${name}!</h1>
<h3>This page was visited: <strong>${counter}</strong> time</h3>
</body>
</html>
```

Почему counter увеличивается на 2 вместо 1:
Запускал через дебагер... doGet вызывается 2 раза при перезагрузке страницы, но почему?
Деплоил на tomcat
(полностью код: на [гитхабе](https://github.com/u169/simpleServlet))

Comment: Потому, что большинство браузеров делают дополнительный запрос для получения favicon.

Comment: Проверьте в режиме отладки [`req.getRequestURL()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getRequestURL%28%29)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

В общем проблема в том, что деплоил на главную локалхоста(localhost:8080/) и сервлет был доступен по тому же адресу(localhost:8080/):

```
    @WebServlet("/")
    ...
```

Ну решение я нашёл... Даже два (можно применить сразу оба):
1. Конфигурация запуска приложения -> Deployment -> Application context:
   вместо "/" указал "/mysite"
2. Изменить аннотацию @WebServlet("/") на @WebServlet("/servlet")

Comment: Да... помню, что начал лезть во все менюшки подряд и тыкать во всё что не нравится. Но думается мне, что каким-то образом прогрузилась дефолтная favicon, и запрс перестал дублироваться.